# Processing a long audio signal with Conv1D in Keras

Tags: audio, neural-network, keras, convolution, keras-layer

I have a long audio signal `x` which is a 1D list of 100000 samples.

For simplicity, let's say all I want to do is convolve it with a length 15 filter, and end up outputting a target filtered signal `y` of 100000 samples.

So basically, I'm trying to do `y = conv(x, h)` with a 1D CNN, and the filter `h` is to be trained.

What is the best way to do this in Keras? All the examples I find seem to be of the form "Each of the samples is a sequence of length 400 words, and convolution is run along that sequence of 400 words". From that, it seems my only choice is to break the audio signal into chunks of size `sequence_length`, but I'd really rather avoid this, since I basically only have 1 input sequence of length 100000.

Ideally, the code would look like

```
import matplotlib.pylab as P
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Conv1D, Input

x_train = P.randn(100000)
y_train = 2*x_train
x_val = P.randn(10000)
y_val = 2*x_val

batch_size = 64

myinput = Input(shape=(None, 1)) # shape = (BATCH_SIZE, 1D signal)
output = Conv1D(
    1, # output dimension is 1
    15, # filter length is 15
    padding="same")(myinput)

model = Model(inputs=myinput, outputs=output)

model.compile(loss='mse',
              optimizer='rmsprop',
              metrics=['mse'])


model.fit(x_train, y_train,
          batch_size=batch_size, epochs=100, shuffle=False,
          validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

Of course, the big problem here is shaping things correctly.

Comment: I think to be better we could use LSTM. If it is speech recognition then you could split audio signal in to parts based on gap and/or you can try using noise cancellation techniques.

Comment: This example is an oversimplified one just to demonstrate my problem with Conv1D. I'm fully aware Conv1D is not anywhere near the best way of tackling this problem. I just want to know how to use Conv1D in this way, so I can implement my real network, which is loosely based on WaveNets.

Comment: To clarify, I'm not doing anything like speech recognition where the output is discrete. The input is a long audio waveform, and the ultimate output will also be a long audio waveform.

Comment: passing Conv1D output to LSTM. and keep return_sequences = True. try that

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're totally on the right track.

Although you have one sound sample (example`*`), keras will still suppose you have many. The solution is simply have a dimension for that in your input.

Also, keras will expect that your data for convolution has "channels". If you have only one channel (not stereo, for instance), then, have a dimension for it with value one.

So, your input data should be shaped as:

- `(1, 100000, 1)` - if using the `data_format='channels_last'` (default)
- `(1, 1, 100000)` - if using the `data_format='chanels_first'`

This means: 1 sample of a signal with length 100000 and one channel.

All the rest in your model seems pretty fine for the task.

---

If your memory cannot support the entire data at once, then you'd need to divide your audio in chunks. Otherwise, you're good to go. (Notice that when dividing, you might get better results using `padding='valid'`, because "same" would be adding lots of border effects in the cuts).

You might be interested in reading about [WaveNet](https://deepmind.com/blog/wavenet-generative-model-raw-audio/) and its related article.

They use stacked convolutional layers with dilation rates.

---

`*` - In Keras, each "example" is called "sample", although in audio processing, samples are usually the timesteps. So, a complete audio file would be a "sample" in Keras.

Comment: why is wavenet able to work without the spectrogram? most models I see rely on this transform